# Column names and apostrophes

Tags: mysql, database, hsqldb

I'm quite new to MySQL and I'm confused with one problem: I have one table on which I cannot perform queries without apostrophes surrounding column names, but for the rest of tables it is possible. I need to do queries without apostrophes to be able to do the same on parrarel HSQL database. On what is it dependent? All tables in MySQL are InnoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table/column name(s) has a reserved keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

You need apostrophes if a column name is a reserved word or if it contains blanks or special characters. Same is true for the table name.

Answer (score 2):

Use table names which are not included in `reserve words` then you didnot need apostrophes(`).